# Using a css class if URL is (value)

Tags: javascript, html

I'm quite new to css / javascript so I'm sorry for this dumb question.
I want to use a css class if the URL matches my criteria.
My try:

```
<script>
    if ((document.URL) == 'http://www.test.testsite.testtest.com/products/#') {
</script>
        <div class="success">
        content
        </div>
<script>
    }
    else {
</script>
        <div class="nosuccess">
        content
        </div>
<script>
    }
</script>
```

The result: It just displays nothing. Probably a simple mistake, but as I said, I'm quite new to javascript.

Thanks for help!

Comment: I've never seen this syntax before :'D seems like you're confused between php and javascript

Comment: this reminds of Java scriptlet.  Javascript is not Java, you cannot do something like that

Comment: Yeah, you guys are right. Dumb question ^^ But the answers below helped a lot in understanding how javascript works.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I recommend you to **separate** the `HTML` from `JavaScript`.

I added and `id` (content) to the div that i want to change the `class`. I make use of `document.getElementById('content')` to get the tag that i want the class to be changed.

After I get the tag I want to change the class, to do that,  make use of property `.className` to change the `class`.

**Notes:** Make sure that the `script` tag is **after** the `HTML` you want to change.

```html
<div id="content">
  content
</div>

<script>
if ((document.URL) == 'http://www.test.testsite.testtest.com/products/#') {
     document.getElementById('content').className = "success";
} else {
     document.getElementById('content').className = "nosuccess";
}
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
<script>
    if ((document.URL) == 'http://www.test.testsite.testtest.com/products/#') {
            var node = document.createElement("div");
            var textnode = document.createTextNode("content");  
            node.setAttribute("class", "success");
            node.appendChild(textnode);
            document.getElementById("div-id").appendChild(node);
          }
     else{
            var node = document.createElement("div");
            var textnode = document.createTextNode("content");  
            node.setAttribute("class", "nosuccess");
            node.appendChild(textnode);
            document.getElementById("div-id").appendChild(node);
        }
    </script>
```

You should not use direct HTML content in if else part of javascript, instead use javascript to append the desired output.